# AndEngine - How to use scroll feature with CameraScene or ChildSene

Tags: android, scroll, andengine

I working on game, in that i want put game levels icon on Camera Scene.
Here i want to use scrolling feature. How do this ?

Ex. Consider, I want to place 20 level icons on Camera scene.
At a time only 10 level icons is visible and after scrolling (horizontally or vertically) Camera Scene remaining 10 level icons is visible.

For do this, What i want to do ?
Is it possible? or What is the other way to scroll level icons?

Answer (score 0):

This what you are looking for I think [link](http://www.andengine.org/forums/tutorials/menu-scroll-example-t5740.html)